# Onkeydown in Textbox how to select and highlight a DataGridRow in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a textbox for search.Now when I will type some text then if the text matches one column of a datagrid row then that entire row will be highlighted and selected .Also I need that selected row data.How to implement it in WPF and I am using MVVM .